# Some Vaadin components not rendered after upgrading from v22 to v24

Tags: java, vaadin

After upgrading from Vaadin 22 to 24 some built-in components like combo-box o grid are not displaying in an application that worked properly with Vaadin 22.
We are using:

- Vaadin 24.1.1 with npn, Vite and production mode.
- Spring Boot 3.1.1

  The logs of the application shows this messages:

```
2023-07-07T10:58:56.045+02:00 ERROR 3404 --- [http-nio-9012-exec-9] c.v.flow.component.internal.UIInternals  : The component class com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox includes '@vaadin/combo-box/src/vaadin-combo-box.js' but this file was not included when creating the production bundle. The component will not work properly. Check that you have a reference to the component and that you are not using it only through reflection. If needed add a @Uses(ComboBox.class) where it is used.
2023-07-07T12:55:41.395+02:00 ERROR 19744 --- [http-nio-9012-exec-2] c.v.flow.component.internal.UIInternals  : The component class com.vaadin.flow.component.details.Details includes '@vaadin/details/src/vaadin-details.js' but this file was not included when creating the production bundle. The component will not work properly. Check that you have a reference to the component and that you are not using it only through reflection. If needed add a @Uses(Details.class) where it is used.
```

And the source code of the generated page has a empty label of vaadin-combo-box:

```
<vaadin-combo-box></vaadin-combo-box>
```

We have deleted node_modules and fronted directories generated by Vaadin several times but nothing changes. Can anyboy help us?

Comment: Did you do a production build?
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/production-build Had the build
any errors?

Comment: Yes, I did a production build and prepare-frontend and build-frontend had not any errors.

Comment: And others vaadin component one would consdier "core", let's say Button, are just fine?

Comment: Do you have anything odd in the dev-console in your browser once the
broken site loads?

Comment: We  have realised that adding @Uses annotation to the view the components are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We register the routes dynamically using a code like the following:
`RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope().setRoute("home", HomeView.class, MainLayout.class);`

where `MainLayout.class` extends the `AppLayout`

The problem is that the components used in `HomeView.class` and not used in `MainLayout.class` are not displayed.

We had to add the annotation `@Uses` to `MainLayout.class` with the components, for example:

`@Uses(ComboBox.class)`

and now all components are displayed properly.

Other solution is to use the property `<optimizeBundle>false</optimizeBundle>` in the `build-frontend` goal of the pom.xml

This behaviour is very odd beacause in Vaadin 22 the application worked fine without the `@Uses` annotation.